# Cannot read property 'getElementsByTagName'

Tags: javascript, xml

I want to create script, that returns all data from table(written in XML) and prints it out.

In this moment I have:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>head</head>

<body>
<p id="demo">body</p>


<script>
function loadXMLDoc(){

 if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
  xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
 } else {
  xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
 }
 
 xmlHttp.open("GET", "Czlonkowie.xml", true);
 xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200) {
   myFunction(xmlHttp);
  } 
 };
    xmlHttp.send();
};

function myFunction(xml){
 var xmlDoc = xmlHttp.responseXML; 
 
 //parser = new DOMParser(); 
 //xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xmlDoc,"text/xml"); // Parse string

 
 var IdentyfikatorCzlonka = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("IdentyfikatorCzlonka")[0];
 var Imie = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Imie")[0];
 var Nazwisko = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Nazwisko")[0];
 var DataUrodzenia = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("DataUrodzenia")[0];
 var Ulica = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Ulica")[0];
 var Miasto = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Miasto")[0];
 var Wojewodztwo = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Wojewodztwo")[0];
 var KodPocztowy = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("KodPocztowy")[0];
 var Email = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Email")[0];
 
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = IdentyfikatorCzlonka;//.nodeValue;
 
}

</script>

<script>
loadXMLDoc()
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

And this is DataBase, written in XML:

```html
<Czlonkowie>
  <IdentyfikatorCzlonka>1</IdentyfikatorCzlonka>
  <Imie>Katarzyna</Imie>
  <Nazwisko>Szewczyk</Nazwisko>
  <DataUrodzenia>1977-01-09</DataUrodzenia>
  <Ulica>ul. Główna</Ulica>
  <Miasto>Łódź</Miasto>
  <Wojewodztwo>łódzkie</Wojewodztwo>
  <KodPocztowy>12-456</KodPocztowy>
  <Email>kasia@mail.com</Email>
</Czlonkowie>
<Czlonkowie>
  <IdentyfikatorCzlonka>2</IdentyfikatorCzlonka>
  <Imie>Bogdan</Imie>
  <Nazwisko>Rawecki</Nazwisko>
  <DataUrodzenia>1987-01-09</DataUrodzenia>
  <Ulica>ul. Mała</Ulica>
  <Miasto>Poznań</Miasto>
  <Wojewodztwo>wielkopolskie</Wojewodztwo>
  <KodPocztowy>34-565</KodPocztowy>
  <Email>bogdan@mail.com</Email>
</Czlonkowie>
```

I got Error:

```
Cannot read property 'getElementsByTagName' of null
```

How solve it?
It looks like my post is mostly code, so they want me to add some more detalis.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML; ` instead of `var xmlDoc = xmlHttp.responseXML; `

Comment: the problem still exists